# Where can I find previous versions of Azure Service Fabric SDKs?

Tags: azure, sdk, azure-service-fabric

I need to find older SDK versions of Azure Service Fabric SDK (2.1.163 to be precise). It is no longer available on Web Platform Installer and couldn't find it anywhere else too.

Can someone please point me to that?

Many thanks!

Comment: By the way, you can find announcements in [SF blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureservicefabric/), open doc file and find links on runtime at the bottom of the document.

Comment: Yes. Thanks for pointing that out. I actually downloaded the release notes but unfortunately skipped opening it as I downloaded another .exe from some other side. My bad!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are the links. Install in this order:

1. Runtime:
   http://download.microsoft.com/download/C/9/6/C9680A4C-291F-4A6F-B699-26FF704577BA/MicrosoftServiceFabric.5.1.163.9590.msi
2. SDK:
   http://download.microsoft.com/download/C/9/6/C9680A4C-291F-4A6F-B699-26FF704577BA/MicrosoftServiceFabricSDK.2.1.163.msi
3. VS Tools:
   http://download.microsoft.com/download/E/7/6/E76A0B84-6DAB-4734-85E2-5912A1130FB4/MicrosoftAzureServiceFabricTools.VS140.en-us.msi

Comment: Thanks for the quick help!