# Where can old versions of Azure Service Fabric SDK be downloaded in order to uninstall it?

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I was trying to setup the latest Azure Service Fabric SDK (2.8.232), but it turned out that I already had previously installed version of SDK (2.0.135). Somehow I have no original `msi` package of that version which results in being unable to uninstall old version.
I am not sure why Web Platform Installer cannot locate and download the package in order to uninstall, so it just fails with `Product: Microsoft Azure Service Fabric SDK -- Error 1714. The older version of Microsoft Azure Service Fabric SDK cannot be removed.  Contact your technical support group.  System Error 1612.`

My guess is that it will work if I can bring the old msi package back at the searched location. But where can I find it? I searched almost everywhere without any success.

It seems that similar questions were asked ([Where can I find previous versions of Azure Service Fabric SDKs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40212235/where-can-i-find-previous-versions-of-azure-service-fabric-sdks)) but there was no clear answer if a specific version was available.

#### Details:

- Product to install: Microsoft Azure Service Fabric SDK 2.8.232
- Error: `Product: Microsoft Azure Service Fabric SDK -- Error 1714. The older version of Microsoft Azure Service Fabric SDK cannot be removed.  Contact your technical support group.  System Error 1612.`
- Old product that cannot be uninstalled: Microsoft Azure Service Fabric SDK 2.0.135

Comment: If you don't find it in the Add/Remove programs - then try here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureservicefabric/2016/05/06/release-of-service-fabric-sdk-2-0-217/ - if you still have issue, raise an issue here: https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues/

Comment: @MikkelMørkHegnhøj it is there in Add/Remove programs, but it cannot find location of the package. The link goes to a bit higher version, so doesn't work for me. I raised an issue there, thank you. Hopefully somebody is going to answer.